# How to enable FIPS endpoint for govcloud AWS gateway (for lambda)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tls1.2, gateway, fips

I have a invoke URL as follows: https://ccvddddXXXXX.execute-api.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/beta I want to implement a FIPS endpoint (so that we are TLS 1.2 compliant). I'm missing the fundamental step here. Is the FIPS endpoint automatically? This doesn't work: https://ccvddddXXXXX.execute-api-fips.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/beta I'm not too familiar with the CLI, so if there is something non-UI can you help provide syntax? thanks!

Comment: As far as I can see in the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/fips/#FIPS_Endpoints_by_Service), only the control plane API endpoints are FIPS. If you have access to a TAM or AWS Support then you might want to ask them what the situation is wrt data plane endpoints.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to official govcloud [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/govcloud-abp.html):

```
All API Gateway APIs created in GovCloud regions are FIPS-compliant by default.
```